# JAVA / PHP: How to insert multiple rows with java and php into DB? (using mysqli)

Tags: java, php, mysqli

I want to insert N number of rows  in a mysql table called USERS. For inserting a single row I write this code (it works):

**PHP side: insert_user.php**

```
<?php   
    $mysqli = new mysqli('hostname', 'username','password', 'dbname');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Can't connect Errorcode: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit;
    }

    if ($result = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `imei`) VALUES (?,?)")) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $imei = $_POST['imei'];

        $result->bind_param("ss", $email, $imei);
        $result->execute();
        $result->close();
        printf("Insert OK");
    } else {
        printf("Insert KO. ERROR: %s",mysqli_error());
    }

    $mysqli->close();     
?>
```

**JAVA side**

```
public void insertUser(String email
             , String imei) {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", imei));

    // send them on their way
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myserver.com/insert_user.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

---

**THE QUESTION**

I need a little complete example for "**insert_*multi*_user.php**" and the relative java method, to pass more rows (using an Array? a Collection? I don't know...).
For instance, replacing this java lines:

```
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", imei));
```

with arrays (?):

```
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email[]));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", imei[]));
```

and, in php, replacing:

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $imei = $_POST['imei'];
```

with:

```
    $email[] = $_POST['email'];
    $imei[] = $_POST['imei'];
```

(obviously the above code is only to give you the idea, it is not correct...)

I spent days with no luck :(
Thank you,
Geltry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your code with for loop

If you have a record/array with users you can do something like

```
$users = array(...);
foreach($users as $user) {
    $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `imei`) VALUES (?,?)")l
    $result->bind_param("ss", $user['email'], $user['imei']);
    $result->execute();
    $result->close();
}
```

But to do that you have to change the way you submit your data, so don't do it one by one rather submit a CSV file for example, parse it with [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and run through each of the records.

On the Java side you can also pass a POST array:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[0][email]","email1"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[0][imei]","imei1"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[1][email]","email2"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user[1][imei]","imei2"));
```

The other options is to send the data in JSON format to the PHP script and use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @Geltrude I think that is the best approach. For web services XML and JSON are perfect match and it's also the easiest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can pass an Array (from Java) into the HTTP post as an argument to the PHP script.  So, basically, your Java code needs to send 1 user at a time in the POST request to add users... so you wrap that in a loop.

There might be a way to serialize the Object Array and send it as a payload to the PHP script where the PHP script can deserialize it, but I am not aware of how you would do such a thing except that you could serialize your array into a XML file.  The PHP script could then read the XML and loop within the PHP script to add the users.